# How to find out if a previous request is running in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have an android application that sends requests to an asp.net website and receives the response.

asp.net mvc controller receives the request and starts the android emulator on server and does something and sends the response.

The problem is when two simultaneous requests arrive I want to either queue the second request or find out if previous request is running and if so, wait for a specified time and then start doing its thing (running emulator).

The second solution is simpler, so I wanna know if there's a way to know if a previous request is running in asp.net.
thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a static boolean which you set when the process starts and clear when the process stops.
Keep in mind to check and set in a thread safe way, eg by  using "lock"